# Создать письмо при ошибке db yii2

Tags: база-данных, yii2

Где в приложении можно или нужно вызвать такой метод, чтобы при любой ошибке db отправлять себе письмо с сообщением кода ошибки?

Comment: Есть смысл, если не коннектится, а в остальных случаях разве это необходимо? Перехватывать исключение, если нет соединения и отправлять уведомление.

Comment: да, туда данные идут автоматически, и если база "отвалится" то, желательно знать об этом. Я так понимаю что нужно выловить db exception, не пойму где это нужно сделать

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько. Один из наиболее простых, это создать свой экшн, на который слать запросы с исключениями. По умолчанию в Yii2 в конфиге определен путь.

```
'components' => [
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
]
```

В контроллере, соответственно указываем класс, который обработает этот экшн

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'CustomErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Свой класс наследуем от дефолтного юишного `yii\web\ErrorAction` и в методе init() своего класса (предварительно вызвав метод родителя) можно отловить необходимое исключение и вызвать необходимые события или метод, который отправит уведомление.